# Python embedding -- how to get the if() truth test behavior from C/C++?

Tags: python, embedded-language

I'm trying to write a function to return the truth value of a given PyObject. This function should return the same value as the if() truth test -- empty lists and strings are False, etc.
I have been looking at the python/include headers, but haven't found anything that seems to do this. The closest I came was PyObject_RichCompare() with True as the second value, but that returns False for "1" == True for example.
Is there a convenient function to do this, or do I have to test against a sequence of types and do special-case tests for each possible type? What does the internal implementation of if() do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this it, in object.h:

```
PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *);
```

?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for the answer! (I was grepping the headers for "bool" and "Bool" and "Compare" and "Test" and found nothing)

I actually just found it too, by getting the source, grepping through the parser until I got JUMP_IF_TRUE, then looking through ceval.c until I got to JUMP_IF_TRUE and saw that it used PyObject_IsTrue. Maybe I'll just use the source code, rather than the documentation from here on out :-)

Comment: The source code is the definitive answer to most questions.  8-)  And the Python source code is very easy to understand - it's surprisingly self-consistent and predictable for a codebase with many authors.  When I read your question I thought "I bet the function's called IsTrue", and sure enough it was.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`int PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *o)`
Returns 1 if the object o is considered to be true, and 0 otherwise. This is equivalent to the Python expression not not o. On failure, return -1.

(from [Python/C API Reference Manual](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html))